# How to identify words in Column A Sheet1 that match words in Column B, then copy those Rows to Sheet2?

Tags: excel, vba

1. I paste from 1 to 30+ different words into Column A, Sheet1 (one word per cell).
2. The code has to loop through Column A and Column B (to see if words in Column A match words in Column B).
   Column B is populated with thousands of different words (one word per cell).
3. When words in Column B match words in Column A, the rows for the matching words in Column B are copied into Sheet2.

Sheet2 has the same headers as Sheet1 (there may be 25+ different Column headers), so the rows copied to Sheet2 will line up.

I need to repeat this process each time with different words in Column A.

`Value = "NAME"` worked for one word:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For I = 5 To a
    
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 1).Value = "NAME" Then
    
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(I).Copy
    
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    
        End If
    Next
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code you have for just one word? Please include it in your question.

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 5 To a

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(I, 1).Value = "NAME" Then

        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(I).Copy

        Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub

Comment: Sorry, the formatting is lost when I paste the code in the comments section. This worked when I substituted different words for Value = "NAME".  I also tried using Value = "NameA" or NameB" or "NameC" - but it did not work.

Comment: What is the source of these up to 30+ words? A column on a worksheet?

Comment: June7:  thanks for your feedback.  But perhaps I did not describe things properly because your revisions (deletions only) of certain lines of code did not work. The 30+ words (or up to thousands of unique words) in Column A could be anything (e.g. names of people or types of services or types of products, etc.  For each of the words, the remaining Columns B, C, D, etc contain unique information for each Row. There could be 1000+ rows. Want to be able to change the code each time to selectively search and copy, paste only those rows per the revised code.

Comment: Also I don't think revising code for every unique search isbest  way to do this.  However original question I posted was deemed not specific enough or too convoluted.  Again, preference was code for the following: 1) I paste any number of unique names or text into cells in Column A. 2) Column B contains thousands unique names per cell/row.  3) The code searches Column B for each of the names I pasted into Column A, and copies each of the Rows containing those names to Sheet2.  So every time paste new names into Column A, do not have to change code to include those names. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, that's not quite what your original question asks for. No mention of copying search words in Column A for matching with Column B (or are you saying you need to match every column?). I did ask what the source would be for these search words. So code will have to loop through words in Column A and loop through Column B to test for match. Let me look at this some more and revise my answer. You should edit question to better explain this requirement.

Comment: Sorry, again I am new to VBA and this is the first forum I have ever used so I'm trying but finding I am not presenting details of my question correctly.  I will try to edit my question.  Really appreciate your feedback and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code will loop through Sheet1 ColumnA to get search word then loop through Sheet1 ColumnB to test for match and if matched, copy row to Sheet2.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Activate
    .Cells(1, 1).Select
    a = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    b = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 5 To a
        For j = 5 To b
            If .Cells(j, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Value Then 
                .Rows(j).Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

This version of code does not physically 'hop' around sheets.

The code will find only exact matches. If you need to find string within string, use LIKE and wildcard or InStr() function, such as: `If .Cells(j, 2).Value LIKE "*" & .Cells(i, 1).Value & "*" Then`

Be aware, my testing shows this code is case sensitive: Apple <> apple.

Comment: June7:  wow, as the saying goes you are a scholar and a gentleperson.  My trying to revise my prior code or search for a solution on my own was like the blind leading the blind.  You provided a solution so quickly.  Thank you very much for being so gracious with your knowledge and time.  Thank You!